# Чем заменить lookbehind утверждение (?<=...) в регулярном выражении?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, firefox

В JS есть поддержка lookbehind только с ECMA2018, поэтому в firefox оно не работает. Чем можно заменить вырожение вида `/(?<=X)/`, чтобы оно работало также, но без использования lookbehind?

Comment: Скорее всего, ухищрения будут зависеть от конкретной ситуации. Несколько примеров можно посмотреть здесь: [Manually Implementing Lookbehind](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch19.html#regexp-look-behind).

Comment: Через неделю заработает и в FireFox. Труднее всего найти альтернативу при использовании регулярного выражения в `split`.